# preg_match latin and other symbols

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate a business name using preg_match and i'm having trouble with specific characters.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ-!@#$%.'& ]*$/,$businessname){echo "error";}
```

It seems to work fine except for the ' and &.   I've tried escaping them, but still no luck.

charset="UTF-8"

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$businessname = 'Ásgarðr \'& Óðinn';
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ\-!@#$%.\'& ]*$/',$businessname)) { 
    echo "error";
} else {
    echo "passed";
}
```